# In TypeScript, why is it not an error to access (get) property that only has a setter?

Tags: typescript

Why does this compile? (TS v2.0.3)

```
class SetterOnly {
  set prop(v) {
    let x = this.prop;
  }
}
```

I would expect `this.prop` to generate a compile-time error ...

Answer (score 9):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/814

> We're definitely not bothering with write-only properties. This is not common enough to justify complicating the type system with it.

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript doesn't have a concept of `writeonly` at the moment. Simply because there hasn't been much demand for it. It does however have `readonly`:

```
class ReadOnly {
  get prop() {return 123}
}

const readonly = new ReadOnly();
readonly.prop = 123; // Error
```